# Problem with AT command in new GSM module A7672S

Tags: at-command, sim900

My project is to send data to **ThingSpeak** server using GSM module. I had successfully send data to server using **Sim900** module. Now due to some reason I need to migrate **Sim900 to A7672S** GSM. Now I am testing the same **AT** command with my new GSM. Unfortunately it doesn't work.I had searched all over the Internet I didn't get any solution. Can anyone have idea to resolve my problem.
Here's the AT command I used in **Sim900**:

```
AT

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","www"

AT+SAPBR =1,1 

AT+SAPBR=2,1

AT+CIPSHUT

AT+CIPSPRT=0

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","api.thingspeak.com","80"

AT+CIPSEND=100

GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=IUDQK1RVPI78YSBA&field1=23.7
```

Only **AT** I got **OK** , Remaining commands I got **Error**

I would like to know if there is any **Alternative** AT commands for **ThingSpeak Server**. And also I had no choice to change the **A7672S** module.

Comment: different module → different commands

Comment: @KlausD. I can't able to find correct documentation for A7672S GSM, And also I tried with Chat GPT , It is also giving wrong AT command.

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to run with `AT+CMEE=2` to get more descriptive error messages (the default `ERROR` is just default for backward compatibility). And you can check what AT commands a device supports by running `AT+CLAC`.